# Command 'gradle' not found. How can I run the gradle command from any directory?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gradle

I am trying to learn gradle build.

I followed [these instructions on gradle.org](https://gradle.org/install/#close-notification).

To verify it i am issuing command.

```
gradle -v
```

I get this output:

```
Command 'gradle' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gradle
```

But after issuing this command from the installation link

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.10.2/bin
```

the above command shows gradle version in my computer.

But the problem is once I close the terminal and issue the command I get the error `command not found`, and once again if I issue the `export PATH`... command, then the `gradle` command starts working.

So how do I add this path permanently so I can issue the `gradle` command from anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `~/.bashrc` and add the `export  ...` command there.

Comment: As per your suggestion added this and it started working 
    GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-4.10.2
    PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
    export GRADLE_HOME
    export PATH